# SharePoint 2016 Sub-site header image is not changing after master page update

Tags: master-page, header

I have a master page which is being inherited to sub-sites as well in our SharePoint 2016 site collection. Now I got a requirement for a sub-site which should have a different header other than its top level site. I updated the master page and set it as default master page from SharePoint designer but it is not getting replicated. Is there a way to change the header so that it won't replicate my top level masterpage to my sub site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it finally. Created a blank master page (e.g **new.master**) from the SharePoint Designer 2013 and then pasted the master page code of Top level site in to the new master page. Turned off the **publishing feature** from sub-site. Then from the s4-notdlg change the banner referring to the Site Assets where I have stored my image as shown below.

```
<div id="pea-header" class="s4-notdlg">
                <img src="/sites/topsite/subsite/Site%20Assets/bannerDP.png" alt="" width="100%" style="text-align:center" />
            </div>
```

Then Right click on the new.master from designer and make as Default master page and Custom master page.

Viola! done I can see my banner for just sub-site has been changed.
Hope it helps others who come across this.